# search sql using ahref links. links at the bottom. return all the rows under that col

Tags: php, html, sql

This is not all the code but basically it searches my sql database using WHERE one col, by $find. I need to make a set of links (at the bottom) link to the sql database in the same way.

tltr: make links search database and return entire column of link clicked.

```
<?php
session_start();
$searches=$_SESSION['numsearches']=0 ;
$find = $_POST['input_value'];
$search =  $_POST['sex'];
$conn = mysql_connect(hidden);
mysql_select_db(hidden);    

if(strcmp($search,"diameter")==0){
$cdresult =  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM drills WHERE `diameter` LIKE '%$find%'");
array_push($my_array, "$find");
}

?>
<!---- LINKS----->
ID<BR>Diameter<BR>Shank<BR>LOC<BR>OAL<BR>Item Number<BR>Price<BR>Altin Number<BR>
Altin Price<BR>Description
```

Comment: what is the problem? what have you tried yet?

Comment: i need to make that list of links search the sql database correspondingly to the name of the link going to the WHERE section of the like search

Comment: maybe if I named the Links with a php $var and use the same variable to search